# CSV to SQLite error using csvs_to_sqlite package

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I'm using [csvs_to_sqlite](https://github.com/simonw/csvs-to-sqlite/tree/main) to import CSV files into an SQLite database. The package uses Python Click as a CLI but I've figured out how to call the function in my Python script:

```
from csvs_to_sqlite import cli
import click


@click.command()
@click.pass_context
def convert_csv(ctx):
    args = {"paths":"bigmac.csv", "dbname": "bigmac.db"}
    ctx.invoke(cli.cli, **args)


def main():
    convert_csv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this error:

```
Could not load ./bigmac.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-log2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-arcsinh.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-arctanh.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-sin.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-cos.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-cbrt.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-arctan.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-cosh.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-expm1.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-sinh.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-tanh.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-log10.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-arcsin.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-arccos.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-log1p.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-log.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-exp2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-arccosh.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-tan.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/tests/data/umath-validation-set-exp.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/philox-testset-1.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/philox-testset-2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/sfc64-testset-1.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/sfc64-testset-2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/mt19937-testset-2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/mt19937-testset-1.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/pcg64-testset-1.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/pcg64-testset-2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/pcg64dxsm-testset-1.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Could not load ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/data/pcg64dxsm-testset-2.csv: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
Loaded 0 dataframes
Created bigmac.db from 31 CSV files
```

An empty SQLite database is created with no tables. The CSV file is not corrupted (I was able to import and query it in DuckDB). Why is the conversion failing?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using an older version of pandas in your setup. Do you know which version is in your environment?

Comment: @AlecBrooks my requirements.txt has pandas == 2.0.3 which is the latest.

Comment: Looks like it's an existing issue for this library https://github.com/simonw/csvs-to-sqlite/issues/88 almost 2 years now